# Pandas/Python: Replacing column values from another column values using .replace()

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace

**Data:**

[image: screenshot]

```
import pandas as pd
dict= {'REF': ['A','B','C','D'],
        'ALT': [['E','F'], ['G'], ['H','I','J'], ['K,L']],
        'sample1': ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
        'sample2': ['1', '0', '3', '0']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

**Problem:**
I need to replace the values in columns'Sample1' and 'Sample2'. If there is 0, then 'REF' column value should be placed. If 1, then first element of list in column 'ALT' should be placed, if 2, then second element of 'ALT' column list, and so on.
**My Solution:**

```
 sample_list = ['sample1', 'sample2']
    for sample in sample_list:

        #replace 0s 
        df[sample] = df.apply(lambda x: x[sample].replace('0', x['REF']), axis=1)
        #replace other numbers
        for i in range(1,4):
            try:
                df[sample] = df.apply(lambda x: x[sample].replace(f'{i}', x['ALT'][i-1]), axis=1)
            except:
                pass
```

However, because list length is different in every 'ALT' column row, it seems that there is IndexError, and values are not replaced after 1. You can see it from the output:

[image: screenshot]

```
'{"REF":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D"},"ALT":{"0":["E","F"],"1":["G"],"2":["H","I","J"],"3":["K"]},"sample1":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"H","3":"2"},"sample2":{"0":"E","1":"B","2":"3","3":"D"}}'
```

How can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**
If I have NaN value in sample1 or sample2, I can't convert values to int and don't how to skip these values

[image]

So, NaN values should not be converted and stayed NaN

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: In sample 1 you have 2 but only one element in the list

Comment: Even if it is 2 elements, still doesn't work

Comment: My question was more, what should be done in those cases?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your ALT column, K and L should be separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple concatenation of REF and ALT columns and apply :

```py
import pandas as pd
d= {'REF': ['A','B','C','D'],
        'ALT': [['E','F'], ['G'], ['H','I','J'], ['K','L']],
        'sample1': ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
        'sample2': ['1', '0', '3', '0']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df["REF_ALT"] = df["REF"].map(list)+df["ALT"]  # concatenate REF and ALT
df["sample1"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.nan if np.isnan(row["sample1"]) else row["REF_ALT"][int(row["sample1"])], axis=1)
df["sample2"] = df.apply(lambda row: np.nan if np.isnan(row["sample2"]) else row["REF_ALT"][int(row["sample2"])], axis=1)
df.pop("REF_ALT")
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for simple answer! But what I can do if there is NaN value in some of sample columns? then int(row["sample"]) will not work

Comment: In that case you need to replace the NaN values beforehand with .fillna()

Comment: But I need to keep these NaN values and don't replace them, so I can't use either .fillna() or convert to integer

Comment: Ok so please clarify what is the expected output in case of nan

Comment: Expected output is just to keep NaN values (don't replace) in sample column, and replace only numbers

Comment: Ok I just updated the code to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df['sample1'] = np.where(df['sample1'].eq(0), df['REF'],
                         [v[max(i - 1, 0)] for v, i in zip(df['ALT'], df['sample1'].astype(int))])

df['sample2'] = np.where(df['sample2'].eq(0), df['REF'],
                         [v[max(i - 1, 0)] for v, i in zip(df['ALT'], df['sample2'].astype(int))])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  REF        ALT sample1 sample2
0   A     [E, F]       E       E
1   B        [G]       G       G
2   C  [H, I, J]       H       J
3   D        [K]       K       K
```

Note that I use a different input given the one in your example is not valid.

Comment: Thanks! But what I can do if there is NaN value in some of the rows in sample column? then df['sample2'].astype(int)) will not work. How to skip these rows?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
 'REF': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'},
 'ALT': {0: ['E', 'F'], 1: ['G'], 2: ['H', 'I', 'J'], 3: ['K', 'L']},
 'sample1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2},
 'sample2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 0},
})

# create a temp col s that includes a single string with letters:
df["s"] = df.REF + df.ALT.str.join("")    
df["sample1"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["s"][x.sample1], axis=1)
df["sample2"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["s"][x.sample2], axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns="s")
```

output:

```
  REF        ALT sample1 sample2
0   A     [E, F]       A       E
1   B        [G]       B       B
2   C  [H, I, J]       H       J
3   D     [K, L]       L       D
```